# Mapbox GL JS : Popup onclick with external JSON

Tags: geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to display a popup onclick in Mapbox GL JS when the user clicks a polygon (It's a weather warning box during a Flash Flood Warning).

[I have been using this example from Mapbox as a base](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/), and -

[This is my JSON file](http://manidoo.000webhostapp.com/warnings/FFW.json) that I am trying to pull data from.

When I click the polygon, there is no popup. When I mouseover it, the cursor changes - so I know the basic possible issues like filename and directory structure are right.

My code below was modified from the example. I am trying to load the "description" of each polygon : (My map is called "topleftmapbox" and the JSON id is "FFWWarning")

```
// When a click event occurs on a feature in the places layer, open a popup at the
    // location of the feature, with description HTML from its properties.
    topleftmapbox.on('click', 'FFWWarning', function (e) {
        var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
        var description = e.features[0].description;

        // Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that multiple
        // copies of the feature are visible, the popup appears
        // over the copy being pointed to.
        while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
            coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
        }

        new mapboxgl.Popup()
            .setLngLat(coordinates)
            .setHTML(description)
            .addTo(topleftmapbox);
    });

    // The following code below runs correctly and changes the cursor on mouseover.

    topleftmapbox.on('mouseenter', 'FFWWarning', function () {
        topleftmapbox.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });

    // Change it back to a pointer when it leaves.
    topleftmapbox.on('mouseleave', 'FFWWarning', function () {
        topleftmapbox.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
    });
```

I have a feeling that my issue is somewhere in this part of the code :

```
    var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
    var description = e.features[0].description;
```

I am still new with Mapbox and I have tried looking through here and various sources online to fix this. I am hoping the issue is just that I have the description variable set wrong and that I am missing something simple.

Comment: Why do not you use debugging tools built into the browser?

Comment: For `setLngLat` function argument must be specified as a LngLat instance, an object {lng: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, or an array of [<lng>, <lat>]

Comment: I do not understand this. My level of skill is low. It is easier for me to see code to understand what is going on.

Comment: When you click on the polygon - where do you want to show the popup?

Comment: Either inside it or on the edge of the polygon was what I was seeking, either way.

Comment: In fact, anywhere on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged the code that you provided and found that variable `coordinates` was containing an object having array of lat-lng.

Modifying that part should fix the issue.

```
var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][0].slice();
```

In `coordinates[0][0]`, second index determines the position of popup.
Here is the working code. https://jsbin.com/suzapug/1/edit?html,output